# Add a drop-down field in checkout form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, dropdown-attribute

I want to add a `drop-down` here  [image]

I can add `area text` field but when it comes to drop-down, I am facing problem.

Comment: Have you tried https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html ?

Comment: but i want to save them in dabase in quote_address and customer_address what to put in InstallSchema.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: Create module.xml

> app/code/Vendor/CheckoutAdditionalField/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_CheckoutAdditionalField" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 2: Create composer.json

> app/code/Vendor/CheckoutAdditionalField/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "Vendor/module-checkoutadditionalfield",
    "description": "Checkout Additional Field",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-checkout": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "pVendor-4": {
            "Vendor\\CheckoutAdditionalField\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3: Create registration.php

> app/code/Vendor/CheckoutAdditionalField/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_CheckoutAdditionalField',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step 4: Now need to overwrite `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor` process method. So create a plugin,

> Vendor/CheckoutAdditionalField/Plugin/Checkout/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
namespace Vendor\CheckoutAdditionalField\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;




class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['delivery_date'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/date',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'delivery-date'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.delivery_date',
            'label' => 'Delivery Date',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 250,
            'id' => 'delivery-date'
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['drop_down'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                'id' => 'drop-down',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.drop_down',
            'label' => 'Drop Down',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 251,
            'id' => 'drop-down',
            'options' => [
                [
                    'value' => '',
                    'label' => 'Please Select',
                ],
                [
                    'value' => '1',
                    'label' => 'First Option',
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i tried that it just add field in the Fronted buti want to have the info in database

Comment: you can create manually after run below command
`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: so you mean just with this code i will have the two attributes frop down and delivery date in base ????

Comment: page not found  for this link

Comment: check below link
https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date

Comment: thanks for this link but i want to add a field type static select so there is many file not necessary like  date so can you please give me the step to add a filed in database and then display it in checkout step

Comment: you can modify above extension and unnecessary files remove
this extension is very useful and needful
Please check and accept the answer if it's helpful.

Comment: ok just one question to add a dropdown do i need to add a class and Model attribute and put my option there and then call them in install schema or just make the field type text and then put the options like done for drop down in thsi example with jscomponnets ??

Comment: @RakeshDonga, on changing drop down , I need to fill the address field from custom table, how can we add on select feature for the drop down field there?